# Python get values in dictionary inside another dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, namedtuple

I have the following data get by JSON:

```
EVENT = {
         'eventid': '11828346', 
         'acknowledges': [{'alias': 'user1', 'name': 'userXYZ'}], 
         'objectid': '25946', 
         'clock': '1444051689', 
         'object': '0', 
         'acknowledged': '0', 
         'value': '0'
         }
```

So, to get what I want from this dictionary:

```
    for t in EVENT:
        TRIGGERID = t['objectid']
        HOUR = t['clock']
        ACK = t['acknowledged']
```

This part is ok, but how can I get the data from the inner dictionary?

```
[{'alias': 'user1', 'name': 'userXYZ'}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dictionary is stored inside a list (for some strange reason) so you can do

```
inner_dict = EVENT['acknowledged'][0]
```

to get the inner dictionary and then select from it like

```
inner_dict['alias']
```

Comment: A dictionary is a key-value store, I can see this in all data (eventid:11828346, object:0 ...), so why you tell that is a list? If I said some nonsense, sorry, I started to learn python few weeks ago.

Comment: No, I wasn't putting you down. `EVENT` is a dictionary, that is correct. But the value corresponding to the key `'acknowledges'` is a list, which you can see this from the brackets `[]`. This list has only one entry which is a dictionary, denoted by the braces `{}`. So what you have is a dictionary in a list in a dictionary, which seemed strange to me. I know you didn't create the data like that but read it from json.  To select from a list you use integer indices, hence the `[0]` in my answer, which selects the first element, the dictionary, from it.